# Using Address Sanitizer as an alternative to Valgrind

Tags: c, clang, address-sanitizer

I have read that Address Sanitizer is an available alternative to the valgrind. So to get into it, i have started with a simple example. I have written the below given code into use_after_free.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int gArray[100];

int main()
{
int *arr = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
arr[1]=45;
printf("Before Free : arr[1] = %d\n",arr[1]);
free(arr);
printf("After Free : arr[1] = %d\n",arr[1]);
printf("gArray[101] : %d\n",gArray[105]);
return 0;
}
```

I have installed the following libraries :

```
1) apt-get install llvm 
2) apt-get install clang
```

Then I have compiled the code using the following command :

```
clang -O1 -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer use_after_free.c
```

When I executed the binary which has been created using above command, I was expecting some errors from address sanitizer. But I am getting output without any errors. Is there any thing wrong with my approach?

EDIT : I am using ubuntu 12.04, llvm 3.1 and clang 3.1

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct binary ? That program shows the  "ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free ..." here.

Comment: Based on your build command, your binary is probably named `a.out`. Is that the one you ran?

Comment: I have only one source file in my folder. I am using the right binary only. I  have executed a.out. That means something might be wrong with my setup.

Comment: @Leiaz : Do I need to set any path variable for using address sanitizer ?

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: The source compiled on my system exposes "AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free" with an `ABORTING` message after diagnostics output. Linux 3.16.0.4-686-pae, Debian 8, clang 3.5.0

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, I just couldn't resist the joke :) And I agree with the cast part.

Comment: @Durgesh You should already have the llvm tools in your path. And the program shouldn't print "After free ..." as  the sanitizer stops on the first error.

Comment: @Leiaz I have added "/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/bin" to my PATH variable and followed the same procedure again. Still it's not showing any errors

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/byz5icprj/

Comment: I see you also asked on AskUbuntu, you should [avoid crossposting the exact same question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), particularly without even linking them. You could modify your question there to ask if there are other packages to install, or something else to configure. Perhaps indicate in this question too which versions of clang and Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Anyways I could see the errors if i compile the code with gcc-4.8 or above.

Comment: To complement the functionality of address sanitizer for leak detection, I would propose to use leak sanitizer. Address sanitizer is mainly for bounds checking - for a detailed comparison between memory tools check [this](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerComparisonOfMemoryTools) reference.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 brings clang [3.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/devel/clang), [3.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/devel/clang-3.3) and [3.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/devel/clang-3.4), but not [3.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clang&searchon=names). You are either using the 3.0 release (which does not have support for the address sanitizer and silently swallows `-fsanitize=address`) or you are using some unmentioned 3rd-party sources. What does `clang --version` tell?

For a solution: `apt-get install clang-3.4` will resolve your problem.